# Extracting FLAs from an MXP

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Once an MXP has been built, is there any way to un-build, extract, or otherwise view the FLA files from which it was compiled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Once built in to an MXP, the original source is not accessible.